# How can I write a regular expression (regex) to exclude the words US and USA?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a form on my website that a form field for COUNTY. People routinely misread this as COUNTRY and end up putting into the field US or USA.

Is there regex that I can use to exclude the words:

US
USA
us
usa

Thank you.

I searched the internet to see if this has been asked before and it has not been from what I can tell. I don't know how to write regex or expressions either though.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead to exclude a word.

Match `US` optionally followed by `A`.

```html
<form>
County: <input type="text" pattern="(?![Uu][Ss][Aa]?$).*">
</form>
```